# Gatsby.js and redux-promise middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, gatsby, redux-promise

I'm wondering if anyone knows if redux-promise (or redux-thunk) will work as middleware in the `gatsby.js` static site generator.  I know that gatsby has redux under the hood, so I'm wondering if there are any conflicts when extra/other redux packages are introduced.

Comment: It would be good to have an answer to this, wondering the same thing...  I have a basic redux thunk function call that is not triggering the thunk part of things, as far as I can tell...

Comment: There is a possibility that this is a solve :  https://gist.github.com/azamatsmith/ab814c869e81dc01b07782be0493ebcd

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the Gatsby Repo that demonstrates how to configure a Redux store with Gatsby: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/examples/using-redux

Comment: This repo does not use thunk and therefore does not directly address the question.